# Apple Watch : I want to add a separator to my group, but I can't because it forces all the labels to go down

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

This is a little hard to explain, but basically I have a group also known as `WKInterfaceGroup` I have three labels. I need them on their own separate line inside the group which I am able to achieve by changing the group layout to vertical. The end result is this [image]

However, now I want to add a small separator on the side. Everyone recommends me to use groups for this. So I try doing this and this is what I get.

[image]

It seems to automatically push my labels down. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What happens if you decrease the number of letters for your labels? Try Label1, Label2 & Label3.

Comment: You mentioned that you want to add a small separator, but the orange bar seems big. Are you looking at overlapping separator with line? If not, fine positioning is possible. Can you add a mock on how you want UI to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the separator on the left and the labels on the right probably what you want is composing two groups.

You need an horizontal group that has two elements: your separator on the left side and a vertical group on the right. Then you can put your labels in the right (vertical) group.

Remember that the layout on the apple watch is automatic, and with groups you can either stack elements vertically or horizontal. To achieve both you have to compose groups.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are placing your Separator inside your `Group` that is in Horizontal Layout and beside other elements. Doing this will flip the Separator vertical. Try placing the Separator in between two Groups instead. Like this:

[image]

You can also change your Group to a Vertical Layout and place the Separator between the labels and it will display the Separator Horizontal.